# How can I download Xcode for flutter development

Tags: xcode, flutter

I have been trying to start flutter development with my MacBook with version OS X Yosemite. 
my basic challenge is this, I can't install Xcode that is compatible with flutter development.

How can I find my way around this?

Comment: did you dowload the latest xcode version from apple store ?

Comment: For the latest xCode I think you need to have the latest OSX version if I'm not mistaken.

Comment: Either update to macOS Mojave 10.14.3 or newer and Xcode 10.2+ will work fine, or try to get Xcode 10.1 from https://developer.apple.com/services-account/download?path=/Developer_Tools/Xcode_10.1/Xcode_10.1.xip if you're stuck on High Sierra.